# Oracle 11g PLSQL - Splitting A Record Out Into Constituent Records Over Time - Row Generating

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have a dataset (a view) that has a numeric field "WR_EST_MHs".  If that field exceeds a certain number of man hours (120 or 60, depending on 2 other fields' values), I need to split it out into constiuent records and spread those hours over future weeks.

[image: Result Set from View]

The OH_UG_Key and 1kMCM_Flag fields determine the threshold for splitting.  For example, if the OH_UG = 1 AND 1kMCM_Flag = 'N' and the WR_EST_MHs > 120, then spread the WR_EST_MHs value over as many records as is necessary, in 120 MH increments, changing only the WRSchedDate and WRSchedDate_Key fields (advancing each by one week).

Each OH_UG / 1kMCM_Flag / WR_EST_MHs scenario is as follows:

[image: Scenarios]

This is an example of what I need to do:

[image]

I thought that something like this might work, but I haven't worked with levels before:

```
     with cte  as
  2    (Select * from "STJOF"."vfactScheduledWAWork" 
  5    )
  6  select WR_Key, WP_Key, WRShedDate, DistSA_Key_Hash, CrewHQ_Key_Hash, Priority_Key_Hash, JobType_Key_Hash, WRStatus_Key_Hash, PerfBy_Key, OHUG_Key, 1kMCM_Flag, WR_EST_MHs
  7  from cte cross join table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
  8                                                 connect by level >= WR_EST_MHs / 120
  9                                                ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 10  order by WR_Key;
```

I also thought this could be done with a "tally table" which I have a little experience with.  I really don't know where to begin on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I would say that a "Tally Table" will work if it is applied correctly. (Or, in this case, a tally view.)

First, break the logic for the hour breakout into a function so we don't have case when everywhere like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_hour_breakout(in_ohug_key IN NUMBER, in_1kmcm_flag in varchar2, in_tot_hours in number)  
   RETURN number  
   IS hours number;    
   BEGIN 
 hours:=
        case when in_ohug_key=2 and in_1kmcm_flag='N' and in_tot_hours>60 then 60 else  
            case when in_ohug_key=2 and in_1kmcm_flag='Y' and in_tot_hours>60 and in_tot_hours<=120  then 60 else  
                case when in_ohug_key=2 and in_1kmcm_flag='Y' and in_tot_hours>120  then 120 else  
                    120 
                end   
            end   
        end;
        RETURN(hours);  
      END get_hour_breakout;
```

This way, if the hour breakout logic changes, it can be tweaked in one place.

Second, join to a dynamic "tally" view like so:

```
select wr_key,  
WP_Key,  
wrscheddate+idxkey.nnn*7 wrscheddate,  
to_char(wrscheddate+idxkey.nnn*7,'yyyymmdd') WRSchedDate_Key,  
OHUG_Key,  
kMCM_Flag,  
case when (wr_est_mhs-idxkey.nnn*get_hour_breakout(ohug_key, kmcm_flag, wr_est_mhs))>=get_hour_breakout(ohug_key, kmcm_flag, wr_est_mhs) then get_hour_breakout(ohug_key, kmcm_flag, wr_est_mhs) else wr_est_mhs-idxkey.nnn*get_hour_breakout(ohug_key, kmcm_flag, wr_est_mhs) end  wr_est_mhs  
from yourView inner join (SELECT ROWNUM-1 nnn  
FROM   ( SELECT 1 just_a_column  
         FROM   dual  
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 52  
       )  
) idxkey on vwrk.wr_est_mhs/get_hour_breakout(ohug_key, kmcm_flag, wr_est_mhs) > idxkey.nnn
```

By using the connect by level we, in effect, generate a bunch of zero indexed rows, then by joining to it with the hours divided by the breakout greater than the feed number we get a few rows for each group.

For example, if the function returns 120 and the hours are 100 you get a single row, so it stays 1 to 1. If the function returns 120 and the hours are 500, however, you get 5 rows because 500/120=4.1666666…, which in the join gives rows 4,3,2,1,0. Then the rest is simple math to determine the number of hours per breakout.

This could also be improved by moving the function call into the lower view so it is only used once per row. And the inline tally view could be made into it's own view, depends on the maintainability you need to build into it.

Comment: This works like a charm.  Perfect solution!   Thanks @MichaelBelzer.  Also, thank you for the formatting and clarifications Jeremy Caney.